# How can I make payment in paypal?

Tags: paypal

how can i make payment using this URL `https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp` and is there any difference  making request from this URL `https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments` and this URL `https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp`. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only way to make payment via paypal is using sandbox, you can use shopping cart or sell single item option which are provided by paypal.com and copy the link to your website or you can add code to your website to send information from your website to the paypal.

Comment: thanks for your answer, you told we can send the information to paypal website right? can make little bit clear. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

yes you can send from html or programming page
look at these codes

const string Server_URL = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?";
const string return_URL = "Your website URL";
const string cancelreturn_URL = "Your website url";
 string cmd = "_xclick";
   string business = "Your paypal ID";
    string item_name = "Your item name";
            double amount = 1;

```
        double handling = 00.00;
        int no_shipping = 0;
        int no_note = 0;
        string currency_code = "MYR"; //Replace with country Currency code
        string lc = "MY";
        string bn = "PP-BuyNowBF";
        string redirect = "";
        redirect += Server_URL;
        redirect += "cmd=" + cmd;
        redirect += "&business=" + business;
        redirect += "&item_name= " + item_name;
        redirect += "&amount=" + amount;
        redirect += "&shipping=" + shipping;
        redirect += "&handling=" + handling;
        redirect += "&no_shipping=" + no_shipping;
        redirect += "&no_note=" + no_note;
        redirect += "&currency_code=" + currency_code;
        redirect += "&lc=" + lc;

        redirect += "&bn=" + bn;
        redirect += "&return=" + return_URL;

        redirect += "&cancel_return" + cancelreturn_URL;
        Profile.SCart = null;
        Response.Redirect(redirect);
```

You can add a button to your website and add these codes for buttion action
There is a test website of paypal, so you can use this and test your code
use this link https://developer.paypal.com/ and create buyer and seller ID

Comment: I created account in sand box. what is lc, bn, bussiness, cmd? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

lc abbreviation of a country MY=malaysia
bn is standard of paypal write like this example
bussiness your paypal id (seller), 
cmd write like this example